# Android app relative layout with 2-3 elements and a bottom button

Tags: java, android, android-layout, listview, android-relativelayout

I want to design an android activity with a relative layout. There should be 3 (or later 4) elements in a vertical line among each other. I've tried it, but the textview is hidden behind the listview.

What's wrong with the code, how should I change it and how should it look, if I want to insert a fourth element between the text and listview or the listview and button ... like a image.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/listview"
        android:text="@string/info" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="start"
        android:src="@drawable/button1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `ReltiveLayout` to `LinearLayout`or put `LinearLayout` outside your RelativeLayout, whith `orientation="vertical"` an put the `TextView` outside `RelativeLayout`. Something like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/textview"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="@string/info" />

   <RelativeLayout
       android:paddingLeft="10dp"
       android:paddingRight="10dp" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">

       <ListView
           android:id="@+id/listview"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_above="@+id/button"
           android:layout_marginBottom="10dp" />

       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/button"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
           android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
           android:onClick="start"
           android:src="@drawable/button1" />

   </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```